# Why setValidators() start using new validators on next change and not right away

Tags: angular, validation, angular5

For example, i have this code which initialize `word` with validator for `minlength` 6 characters. Then when length of `word` is >4 `minlength` is set to 8 characters.

Problem is that, change is not visible right away when you type in fifth char, but it is visible after you type in sixth character or when you delete one or more chars.

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({ 
  word: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]
}, {validator: this.validateNumber});

validateNumber(input: AbstractControl) {
  if(input.get("word").value != null && input.get("word").value.length > 4) {
    input.get("word").setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);
  }
}
```

I create this exmaple on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/33ZMWN9d3BJ1HkNJHLoD?p=preview). When you start typing into input box there is an error for `minlength`, which change from 6 to 8 when you type sixth char and not fifth.

Comment: Why do you even need the minLength of 6 if it's actually 8?

Comment: It's just an example

Comment: Can you try calling `input.updateValueAndValidity()` at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After updating the validators on a field, you need to update the control and its validation. Otherwise, the validators will only be run agains the changes the user will make onto the form.

[Deborah Kurata has shown it in one of its tutorials on pluralsight.](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-ReactiveForms/blob/bb8e28c6b3311f8c78ed60095de2e141febbbed8/Demo-Final-Updated/src/app/customers/customer.component.ts#L109)

What you should do is the following:

```
validateNumber(input: AbstractControl) {
  const wordControl = input.get("word");
  if(wordControl.value != null && wordControl.value.length > 4) {
    wordControl.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]);
    wordControl.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

By the way, if each time you validate, you update the validators and run the validation again, you will have an infinite loop.